# fetch xml cross browser compability

Tags: javascript, xml, cross-browser, dynamics-crm-2011

i have  function that works in IE and does not work in other browsers
please help rewrite it for cross browser compatibility

```
function Fetch(xml) {
var Xml = "<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap=\"http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/\" xmlns:xsi=\"http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance\" xmlns:xsd=\"http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema\">";
Xml += GenerateAuthenticationHeader();
Xml += "<soap:Body>";
Xml += "<Fetch xmlns=\"http://schemas.microsoft.com/crm/2007/WebServices\">";
Xml += "<fetchXml>";

Xml += CrmEncodeDecode.CrmXmlEncode(xml); // Microsoft _HtmlEncode function  

Xml += "</fetchXml>";
Xml += "</Fetch>";
Xml += "</soap:Body>";
Xml += "</soap:Envelope>";

 // Microsot CreateXmlHttp function  
if ( XMLHttpRequest != null){
var XmlHttp  = new XMLHttpRequest();
}
else{
var XmlHttp  = new ActiveXObject("Msxml2.XMLHTTP"); 
}
XmlHttp.open("POST", "/mscrmservices/2007/crmservice.asmx", false); //Sync Request  
XmlHttp.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "text/xml; charset=utf-8");
XmlHttp.setRequestHeader("SOAPAction", "http://schemas.microsoft.com/crm/2007/WebServices/Fetch");
XmlHttp.send(Xml);

var ie = (window.ActiveXObject) ? true : false; 
           var XmlDoc = (ie) ? new ActiveXObject("MSXML2.DOMDocument") : new window.XMLHttpRequest(); 

XmlDoc.async = false;
XmlDoc.resolveExternals = false;

XmlDoc.loadXML(XmlHttp.responseXML.text);
return XmlDoc;
 }
```

how to change the code so that it works in google chrome

Comment: You should probably use a library like jQuery whose Ajax functions are designed to work cross browser.

Comment: What error you have in chrome?

Comment: possible duplicate of [loadXML does not work in chrome](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17784087/loadxml-does-not-work-in-chrome)

Answer (score 0):

[Try this code](http://dotnetdust.blogspot.com/2013/07/making-fetchxml-in-javascript-less.html?showComment=1374062233343).  I'm not sure if it'll work in Chrome, and make sure to see the comments about a possible issue with responseXML vs ResponseText, but it should make the response easier to handle.

And if you're in 2011, why the 2007 endpoint?  It has been deprecated and is not even available for some instances of CRM online, and will not be available for any CRM 2013 instance.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest incorporating the [XrmServicesToolkit](http://xrmservicetoolkit.codeplex.com/) into your solution which is cross-browser and will greatly simplify executing a SOAP request:

```
var request = "<request i:type='b:WhoAmIRequest' xmlns:a='http://schemas.microsoft.com/xrm/2011/Contracts' xmlns:b='http://schemas.microsoft.com/crm/2011/Contracts'><a:Parameters xmlns:c='http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/System.Collections.Generic' /><a:RequestId i:nil='true' /><a:RequestName>WhoAmI</a:RequestName></request>";
var whoAmI = XrmServiceToolkit.Soap.Execute(request);
```